# Send multiple line code to PyDev interactive console at the context of a breakpoint

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I'm using Eclipse Luna 4.4.0 + PyDev 3.7.0.

My goal is to execute a python script and being able to send commands to the console while stopped at a breakpoint, using its context and selecting several lines of code at once, with different indentations, like `for` loops, `if` statements, etc. This would be a similar debugging behavior as with *MATLAB* (selecting code and pressing F9), which I find really useful.

If I press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> without selecting any code the script is executed within the interactive console.
The execution indeed stops at the first breakpoint. I can inspect the variables, but the console does not prompt me for any input. I can select and send commands with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, but they are greyed out, and not interpreted at all. If I'm not stopped at a breakpoint, this method does not support blocks of code with different indentations, like `for` loops, when prompted for commands.

If I run a *normal* debug session, without pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, I can stop at a breakpoint and have some interaction, like typing single commands (displayed in green, not in grey), but I cannot send several commands, and they need to have the right indentation. Launching an interactive console at this point will result in a new console with a new context.

Is there any way to select and send a block of code to the interactive console while being stopped at a breakpoint, using the context at that moment?. Is it possible to do this with any other IDE?

I've seen similar questions in SO like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2045551/3382783), or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25065948/3382783), but this is still unclear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is now, it works at that as an interactive console -- so, the indentation really needs to be right with Ctrl+Alt+Enter, but if you use F2 instead, it should work better (as F2 is meant to fix the indentation and should do what you want)...

Reference: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html

Comment: Thanks.I was unable to put this to work, because F2 was launching a new console. At least this was the default behavior with PyDev 3.9.2.201502050007 and before. I am trying now PyDev 4.0.0.201504132356 and it is fixed (or configured by default).